# Import a submodule of a package while the pacakge is being loaded

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I am importing a package `foo1.foo2`, whose `__init__.py` is importing a submodule `foo1.foo2.foo3.bar1`, which is a file. If I try to import `foo1.foo2.foo3.bar2` inside that file I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'foo1' has no attribute 'foo2'
```

Given that [the use of relative imports is discouraged](http://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#Imports), how can I solve this issue without using relative imports?

---

Here is the package structure and file contents that I have:

```
/
├── foo1
│   ├── __init__.py:
│   └── foo2
│       ├── __init__.py: "import foo1.foo2.foo3.bar1"
│       └── foo3
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├── bar1.py: "import foo1.foo2.foo3.bar2 as bar2"
│           └── bar2.py:
└── main.py: "import foo1.foo2"
```

Running `python main.py` generates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import foo1.foo2
  File "/foo1/foo2/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import foo1.foo2.foo3.bar1
  File "/foo1/foo2/foo3/bar1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import foo1.foo2.foo3.bar2 as bar2
AttributeError: module 'foo1' has no attribute 'foo2
```

I'm using `Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `import foo1.foo2.foo3.bar2 as bar2` into `from foo1.foo2.foo3 import bar2`.

Then it works.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion works! Could you explain why is this happening though? Why "from ... import ..." works and "import ... as ..." does not?

Comment: The file foo1.foo2.foo3.bar1 doesn't belong to me and I can't change it. I'm just updating the foo1.foo2.__init__.py.

Comment: @Pro.Hessam Actually, I'm not sure about it. But it seems importing a file in the same folder in a sub module, you need to specify the scope. Which means you need to use either `from . import bar2` or `from foo1.foo2.foo3 import bar2`. You need to specify the scope which is the module `foo3`, and the reason might be that related to `bar1`, `bar2` is just a file but not a module.